# How to identity element in selenium for below html

Tags: selenium

```
<a href="XXXX.asp?WCI=XXXX_Process&amp;CacheID=123351730222025121&amp;menuopt=Policy&amp;TransTyp=NBS">
   <strong><font face="Arial" color="Navy">New Business - Rate</font></strong>
</a>
```

How to identity element in above html,I tried below code but it didnt work out

1. `driver.findelement(By.cssselector(a[href='given the full href link'])).click ()`--didn't work out due to cacheID is dyanamic
2. `driver.findelement(By.cssselector(a[href*='TransTyp=NBS'])).click ()` --tried with partial word didnt work either

Kindly help me on this.

---

i tried same thing in chrome it works like a charm,even my earlier code works fine with chrome.Not sure if internet explorer has any issue handing them . I am using windows 10 OS and internet explorer comes with it. 
In Internet explorer i can able to login with selenium after the landing page when i want to click new business link its not working,but the same code works fine in chrome.
Is there any reason for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked on this issue after longtime.Its my fault, not aware of Frames concept.
 The webpage i was working involves Frames in Internet explorer.
 Working fine with linktext itself.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should use XPath. And you need two steps here:

1. Find element by text
2. Find closest `a` to element with link text

Here is XPath which does that:

```
driver.findelement(By.xpath("//*[text()='New Business - Rate']/ancestor-or-self::a"))
```

Comment: I have tried Xpath u have given,it has one matching node in Firefox Xpath when i tried same thing in code getting no such element error.

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='New Business - Rate']/ancestor::a")).click();`

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("New Business - Rate"));
```